# I am working on the ASP.NET with C# on the Web based project and I am having the compliation error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.index_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'cmdCheckMail_Click' and no extension method 'cmdCheckMail_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.index_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 270:                                <tr>
Line 271:                                  <td align="right" colspan="2">
Line 272:                                      <asp:Button ID="cmdCheckMail" runat="server" Text="Check Mail" OnClick="cmdCheckMail_Click" Height="22px" Width="90px" />
Line 273:                                    </td>
Line 274:                                </tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the Code Behind model you need to add

```
protected void cmdCheckMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //....your event handling code goes here
}
```

to index.aspx.cs

or else you need to add

```
<script runat="server">
protected void cmdCheckMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //....your event handling code goes here
}
</script>
```

to index.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a method declaration which your page needs. Add to index_asp.cs the following method:

```
public void cmdCheckMail_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your cmdCheckMail_Click method, I sholud look like :

```
protected void cmdCheckMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```